Add local module dependency and publish it in pom

In my project I have multiple modules say A & B.
'A' module has 'B' added as a dependency through implementation project(':B')
On publishing A.aar, the resultant pom file does not have B module in it.
When using A as a dependency in other projects I get error that B is missing in the aar.

I can't publish B as an individual aar, I need it to be included in A.aar

"I can't publish B as an individual aar" -- then why does B exist as a separate module?

Are you able to build your project? Are you publishing to maven in A.gradle?
Can you provide A and B gradle files?

Sorry about the confusion, in this case I am publishing the B as individual aar but everytime I use A, I want B along with it as A is dependent on B.

This question is kind of abstract without the build.gradle, try api project(':B'). To publish locally, this would be repository: mavenLocal(). Libraries shouldn't even depend on other libraries, in best case as meta-package or BOM. There's no rule, but it's still something to better avoid for various reasons.

Martin, please check the build.gradle I have posted above.
Also I tried api project(':B')  which didn't work.

Here are the build.gradles
A's build gradle:
    apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    namespace = "com.example.android.a”
    compileSdkVersion Version.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion Version.buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Version.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion Version.targetSdk
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "r"
        testApplicationId = “”
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled false

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled false
           }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.6'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
        pickFirst 'draftv4/schema'
        pickFirst 'draftv3/schema'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LGPL-3.0.txt'
    }

    task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classifier = 'sources'
    }

    namespace 'com.example.android.a’

    artifactory {
        contextUrl = System.getProperty("url")  //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = System.getProperty("key")
                username = System.getProperty("username")
                password = System.getProperty("pswd")
            }
            defaults {
                publications('release')
                publishArtifacts = true
                publishBuildInfo = true
                publishPom = true
            }
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        // Creates a Maven publication called "debug".
        release(MavenPublication) {
            // AAR of each library
            def buildType = System.getProperty("buildType") ?: "debug"
            artifact "${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${archivesBaseName}-${buildType}.aar"
            artifact sourcesJar
            artifactId ‘A’
            groupId 'com.example.android.A’
            // Add dependencies to POM - normal projects use 'from components.java
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                // Iterate over the 'compile' dependencies
                configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                    if (it.group != null) {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
           
        }
    }
    artifactory {
        contextUrl = System.getProperty("url")
        //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = System.getProperty("key")
                username = System.getProperty("username")
                password = System.getProperty("pswd")
            }
            defaults {
                publications('release')
                publishArtifacts = true
                publishBuildInfo = true
                publishPom = true
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':B')
 }

Here's the build.gradle of B:
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.android.x.B”
    compileSdkVersion Version.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion Version.buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Version.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion Version.targetSdk
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled false
            setProperty("archivesBaseName", “B-${version}")
            resValue "string", "app_version", "${version}"

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled false
            setProperty("archivesBaseName", “B-${version}")
            resValue "string", "app_version", "${version}"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.6'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
        pickFirst 'draftv4/schema'
        pickFirst 'draftv3/schema'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LGPL-3.0.txt'
    }

    task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classifier = 'sources'
    }
    artifactory {
        contextUrl = System.getProperty("url")  //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = System.getProperty("key")
                username = System.getProperty("username")
                password = System.getProperty("pswd")
            }
            defaults {
                publications('release')
                publishArtifacts = true
                publishBuildInfo = true
                publishPom = true
            }
        }
    }
}
publishing {
    publications {
        // Creates a Maven publication called "debug".
        release(MavenPublication) {
            // AAR of each library
            def buildType = System.getProperty("buildType") ?: "debug"
            artifact "${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${archivesBaseName}-${buildType}.aar"
            artifact sourcesJar
            artifactId ‘B’
            groupId 'com.example.android.B’
            // Add dependencies to POM - normal projects use 'from components.java'
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                // Iterate over the 'compile' dependencies
                configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                    if (it.group != null) {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    artifactory {
        contextUrl = System.getProperty("url")
        //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = System.getProperty("key")
                username = System.getProperty("username")
                password = System.getProperty("pswd")
            }
            defaults {
                publications('release')
                publishArtifacts = true
                publishBuildInfo = true
                publishPom = true
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
   …
}

